# GNOME III 12.04 Draws Desktop Off Top Of Screen (Overscan)

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, gnome

With native resolution of 1680 x 1050,  NVIDIA (post-release update) (version current-updates) driver installed, (NVIDIA recommended driver fails to install with bug), GNOME III draws the desktop top bar off the top of the screen (also Unity.)

I have to stare at desktop all day, is there a config file that can be edited?

My screen is also detected as laptop, it is a desktop/tower, (relevant?)  Would a fresh install rectify?  I updated, never had a problem before + migrating files Right Royal PITA.

Thanks.

Comment: I have never had luck with the provided drivers.

Has installing the driver from NVIDIA's site made a difference?

Comment: I reinstalled NVIDIA driver via CLI, copying & pasting commands from another StackExchange post.  Did not help.  As far as I am aware, it jst reinstalled current driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting overscan settings visibly reduces the image quality even when upping the image sharpness.

Solved by adjusting NVIDIA panel settings:

X server Display Config ==> Advanced ==> Panning ==> 1680x1050, & set Panning ==> Mode Name:  **1680x1050_60**